# Code background color depends of using language

Tags: visual-studio-code

It is possible to change text editor background depends of language?
Code beetwen

```
<?php ... ?>
```

and

```
<script> ... </script>
```

with other background color to make it more visible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to use something like [highlight extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight).

And then in your settings:

```
"highlight.regexes": {

   "(<script>\\s*)(\\r\\n)+((.*\\r\\n)*?)(\\s*<\\/script>)" : [
      {},
      {},
      {
        "backgroundColor": "#009",
        "color": "#fff",
      },
      {}
    ],

    "(<script>\\s*)(.*?)(\\s*<\\/script>)" : [
      {},
      {
        "backgroundColor": "#009",
        "color": "#fff",
      },
      {}
    ],

    "(<\\?php\\s*)(.*?)(\\s*\\?>)" : [
      {},
      {
        "backgroundColor": "#009",
        "color": "#fff",
      },
      {}
    ],

    "(<\\?php)(\\r\\n)+((.*\\r\\n)*?)(\\s*\\?>)" : [
      {},
      {},
      {
        "backgroundColor": "#009",
        "color": "#fff",
      },
      {}
    ]
  }
}
```

This edited version should work with multiline examples.

And you **must** `reload` your vscode when you are done editing this into your settings.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It works indeed, but the problem is detect only one line  of code. If I have new line character beetwen tags styling will disappear. @Mark

Comment: That should be fairly easy to fix.  I'll try to get to it later.

Comment: I edited the answer to support multiline versions.  Let me know if it works for you.  And reload.

Comment: still any enter will break styling :s

Comment: I think I fixed the multiline issue with the \\r\\n

Comment: multiline breaks it again